# When I open a querydsl JPA project with vscode, vscode has many cannot be resolved errors

Tags: visual-studio-code, querydsl, generated-code

When I open a querydsl JPA project with vscode, vscode has many cannot be resolved errors:

```
The import com.**.QRoutePayload cannot be resolved
```

When I open it with IDEA, it's all right.
Why do I get this errors in vscode and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

QueryDSL generates code like the Q-classes (e.g. in your example "QRoutePayload") into your maven target folder. IDEA adds the folder of the generated sources automatically but vscode does not.

So the solution is to add the folder of generated sources to your class path. For example with a maven project you can do it with the build-helper-maven-plugin in your <build>:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>target/generated-sources/java</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

You can see what paths are in your class path in vs code by using `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P` > "Java: Configure Classpath". But if the project ist managed by maven this is read only and you have to use the pom as described above.

Answer (score 0):

In order to successfully generate `Q` classes in **VSCode**.

Remove the `apt-maven-plugin` from the `POM`.

Add following dependencies in the `POM`.

Please make sure add the `version` and `classifier` in the `querydsl-apt` dependency with `provided` scope.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
    <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    <classifier>jpa</classifier>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
</dependency>
```